# Cannot detect second display

Tags: 11.10, display

Using the display program I cannot detect the second display which is connected with my desktop PC (running ubuntu 11.10 64bit, gtx 280 gpu) via DVI.
Although using a live CD of linux mint the second screen was used when it loaded, without me having to set anything else.

What can I do?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you using Nvidia's binary drivers or Nouveau? If it's the binary driver, then install and run ``nvidia-settings`` to configure your display (hit the *Detect Displays* button on the *X Screen configuration* and set up TwinView if you like Dual-Head display). And, any reason for running Ubuntu 11.10 now?

Comment: @gertvdijk: I am using nvidia's binary drivers. I've set up the separate x screen but it didn't work as expected..After a logout and login,my main monitor became white and the 2nd monitor became main (where the login manager showed up and where unity appeared).
Why shouldn't I use 11.10? I am expecting for 12.10, to upgrade..I might upgrade it to 12.04 (i just didn't have the time)

Comment: Usually you don't want to use separate X Screens. Try TwinView as I already proposed. Please include more related information like drivers your installed in your question next time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Nvidia's binary driver, try configuring your screen using Nvidia's settings utility (`nvidia-settings` - both executable name and package name).

For dual screen 'extending screen' configurations set the *Configuration* to *TwinView*, like this:

[image: NVIDIA Settings dialog]

You may need to re-trigger the detection of just connected displays by hitting the *Detect Displays* button.

Don't forget to *Save to X Configuration File* if you like to keep your settings persistent across reboots. You may need to run `nvidia-settings` with root privileges by prepending the command with `sudo` or `gksu`.

Comment: I did as you said but now the launcher is at the 15" monitor and I want it to be at the 23" monitor. The order of my monitors on my desk is: left 15", right 23". I want to keep that order with the twinview configuration. Is there any way to display the unity launcher at the 23" screen?

Comment: Did you try to tick the *Make this the primary display for the X screen* checkbox for the screen you want to run your launcher on?

Comment: Yes, it is checked for the 23" monitor but the unity launcher appears at the 15" one.

Comment: @Chris I guess you're hitting a bug somewhere. Try asking a new question, targeted to your (new) issue.

Comment: [This is what I am seeing now](http://tinypic.com/r/ims17t/6). Posted it just to make sure that I've have the correct settings and not getting the correct result.